# Need Help: PDF Files Not Showing Up in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: pdf, adobe-illustrator

I am currently facing an issue while working with Adobe Illustrator and would greatly appreciate your help in resolving it.

The problem I am encountering involves the insertion of PDF files into my Illustrator document. Despite multiple attempts, the PDF files doesn't appear in the document. I have followed the standard process of inserting the files, but they simply do not show up. I have attached a screenshot for reference.

[PDF not showing up instead showing a blue rectangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnVXx.png)

Here are a few additional details that might be relevant:

- I am using the latest version of Adobe Illustrator.
- The PDF files I am attempting to insert have been created using various software and sources.
- I have tried inserting PDF files from different locations on my computer, including both local storage and external devices.
- Other file formats, such as JPEG or PNG, seem to insert correctly without any issues.
- I have tried restarting my computer and reinstalling Adobe Illustrator, but the problem persists.
- I am confident that someone within this forum has encountered a similar situation or possesses the necessary expertise to help me troubleshoot this problem. If you have any insights, suggestions, or possible solutions, I would be incredibly grateful if you could share them with me.

Thank you very much for your time and consideration. I eagerly await your valuable input and assistance.

Comment: Thanks your comment, I can definitely confirm that you can inject a PDF into AI as I have been doing it. However for some reasons this PDF is doing this

Comment: Thanks KJ, I found a solution for it. You need the resave the file in Photoshop as a PDF and then when you added in illustrator it should be working